Add react-native-braintree-dropin-ui to EXPO project
I'm tring to add react-native-braintree-dropin-ui to EXPO project.
Always getting DROP_IN_CLIENT_UNINITIALIZED error.
According to readme file I should place this code somewhere in expo project... but where?
  import tech.power.RNBraintreeDropIn.RNBraintreeDropInModule;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        RNBraintreeDropInModule.initDropInClient(this);
    }

